# tortoise-hg export changeset between revisions

Tags: windows, documentation, tortoise-hg, source-control

Is there a way to export the changelog from tortoise-hg between two revisions?

I'm looking to get a list of all file changes along with the associated commit messages. I need this information to make an exhaustive patch note document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at TortoiseHG 1.1.7 here, so it may not exactly match yours if you're on a newer version, but...

- Go to the Repository Explorer (I think it's called the Workbench in newer versions)
- Right-click on the revision that you want to export
- Choose "Export" from the dropdown
- Chose "Export Patch" from the submenu

This will create a patch/diff file with all of the information that hg needs to recreate the exported revision, including such things as the commit message and the various file changes.